# Laravel 4 - JOIN - Same column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I do currently use this code to retrieve the required data from my database

```
    $query = DB::table('packages')
        ->join('assigned_packages', function($join) use($id)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id')
                ->where('assigned_packages.customer_id', '=', $id);
        })
        ->join('registered_packages', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'registered_packages.id')
                ->on('registered_packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id');
        });
```

It works fine, however the problem is that this tables have columns with the same name, and therefore only the last one is in the result. How can i fix that? Normally i would use the `as` option in the query, but i honestly do not know how I can add it to my current JOIN code from above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = DB::table('packages')
->join(...)
->join(...)
->select(DB::raw('packages.name as name1, assigned_packages.name as name2'))
->get();
```

---

**edit:**

```
$sql = "select a.name as name1, b.name as name2";
$sql .= " from a left join b on a.id=b.id1 and b.id2=&id";
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: This will result in a object which will only include the result from the select queryy (DB::raw) but not the result from the above joins :(

Comment: @Michael Can you paste the final SQL you want?

Comment: What do you mean? I have posted my join query in the question. The only problem is that there are columns in the join that have the same name in both tables, and I therefore need to specify a custom name for them. So your ->select does work, but does not keep the data from the join.

Comment: Can you put those columns into select(DB::raw())?

Comment: As i said.. I did, but it will then only result those columns but not the other data from the join.

Comment: What's the other data? You cannot retrieve data in `join()` method, you should put all columns you want into `select()` method

Comment: No that is not a solution then. I honestly doubt that there is no other way to do that.

Comment: But I still don't know what data you want, like `assigned_packages.registered_package_id`?

Comment: As i said above, the query from my question is working fine and returns the data from both tables, but there are columns in this tables which have the same name, so it does only return the last one. And i therefore need to specify a custom name for this columns. If i simply add the ->select() as you mentioned, it will ignore the joins and therefore only return the data for this ->select()

Comment: I've used it like that before, it wouldn't ignore the joins... Or you can try another way to do it. See my edit.

Comment: But it does :/. Your edit is not a option as i want to utilise the correct functions for that, and a manual query is clearly not the way to go.

Comment: I just checked it, the query will become to something like that: `select registered_packages.lock_until as registered_packages_lock_until from packages inner join.....` so it clearly only request the columns that i specify in the ->select() method.

Comment: I just found my code and checked it again. `select()` definitely works with `join()` sucessfully.

Comment: Yes it works, but as i posted above, it only request the columns that are specific within the select().

Comment: Yes, you should put all columns you want into `select()`, all columns you want in table `packages`, `assigned_packages` and `registered_packages`

Comment: But i can't do that. This are about 120 columns together.. There must be a other solution.

Comment: 120...you can try this `->select(DB::raw("a.*, b.*, c.*, a.name as name1, b.name as name2, c.name as name3"))`, if you don't have many columns with same name.

Comment: Could you please explain this query to me? Thank you.

Comment: `select a.*` means select all columns from table a, then you can get those columns don't have same names; if columns in table a/b/c have same names, `a.name as name1, b.name as name2, c.name as name3` give them alias. So you will select those columns have alias twice(once in `*`, once with alias), but I think it works for you.

Comment: But I can not figure out that you really want to select 120 columns one time?

Comment: Thanks, the last example works. Sadly i have to select that many columns cause they need to get dissplayed at once :/

Comment: In my case just adding * to the raw select when assigning the new column names kept the other join data (L5.1)