# Id Column Overwritten by Join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Using Laravel 4.2 & MySQL.

I have an `applications` table with an `id` and a `fit_score_id` column, and a `fit_scores` table with an `id` column. It's a basic "belongs to" relationship.

The following code:

```
$query = Application::join('fit_scores', 'applications.fit_score_id', '=', 'fit_scores.id');
$collection = $query->get();
```

...produces a collection of `Application` models with the `id` property set to the value of the `fit_score_id`. What am I doing to cause this?

I should note that it is necessary to do this join rather than simply using eloquent relations, because I'm going to want to order the results by a column on the `fit_scores` table. I don't believe this is possible using Eloquent without an explicit join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this is by chaining the ***join*** method to a ***select*** method as following:

```
Application::select('*', \DB::raw("applications.id as appid"))
             ->join('fit_scores', 'applications.fit_score_id', '=', 'fit_scores.id')
             ->get();
```

Explained: The solution simply suggest that instead of thinking to prevent the behavior of overwriting the first id with the joined id, we can hook into the primary selection query (before joining) and change the label of the id column into something else (in this case 'appid'). By doing so, we end up with both the id of the parent table being labeled 'appid' and the id of the joined table being labeled 'id' again while they lives together on the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a possible solution using this answer:

[Laravel 4 - JOIN - Same column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859626/laravel-4-join-same-column-name)

Basically, since Laravel does not automatically prefix column names with `table_name.` for joined tables, we need to manually work around it by aliasing any conflicting column names in joins. Adding this select statement to my query did it:

```
->select(DB::raw("applications.*, fit_scores.*, applications.id as id"))
```

Comment: I'm hoping someone will respond with a better solution, but I think this one is the best we're going to get from Eloquent currently, so I'll probably accept it once the minimum amount of time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need but probably you can achieve it using eager loading. In case you need to mix joins and eager loading check this out. http://www.jmilan.net/posts/eager-loading-joins-in-laravel

Comment: In this instance the goal is to return results sorted by a column on the joined table. Eager loading alone would not work for this, since it still fetches the records from the related table in a separate additional query. This would mean the models would then need to be sorted in PHP after the SELECT. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I missed the order clause in the joined table. Sorry. Have tried using an alias on the joined table id column? I'd say your problem would be resolved by disambiguating this 'id' fields

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing in the accepted solution (`applications.id as id`). I didn't need to alias the id column on the joined table since I didn't need the value of that column.

Comment: Great! I have experienced some problems around joint tables and ambiguous fields. An alias usually solves it. Glad to hear!